# Rhino Mocks, assert that a MockRepository was not used (methods)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Is there a way of asserting that no methods were called in MockRepository?

Say I have:

```
var repo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<RealRepo>();
```

I know I can do:

```
repo.AssertWasNotCalled(...);
```

But is there a way of checking that it was not used? Instead of doing all the methods everytime i want to check if a repo was not used?

I have cases where I want to just check that I don't use this repo.

Comment: If it was not called, it was not used. If it was called, it was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding your own extension to Rhino Mocks. Something like this:

```
    public static void AssertNothingWasCalled<T>(this T mock)
    {
        var methodsToVerify = typeof (T)
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(m => !m.IsSpecialName);

        foreach (var method in methodsToVerify)
        {
            var arguments = BuildArguments(method);
            var action = new Action<T>(x => method.Invoke(x, arguments));
            mock.AssertWasNotCalled(action, y => y.IgnoreArguments());
        }
    }

    private static object[] BuildArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return methodInfo
            .GetParameters()
            .Select(p => Arg<object>.Is.Anything)
            .ToArray();
    }
```

But [the answer by Sergey Berezovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002364/2642204) seems a bit simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Use StrictMock instead of stub:

```
var repo = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<RealRepo>();
```

It will throw exception if you will try to call any member which do not have setup.

---

BTW same is true for Moq:

```
var repoMock = new Mock<RealRepo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked, even though I had to move around a bit the test cases, but it DOES give me the functionality I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to pass a null ref to the calling class. Your SUT should throw a `NullReferenceException` if it attempts to use it. This is possibly the simplest thing that will work.

However, if the SUT checks for null, then this won't work.